# How must the UploadSiteHostedPictures call, of the eBay Trading API, be formatted to successfully upload Base64Binary image data to eBay?

Tags: xml, base64, http-post, mime-types, ebay-api

*Picture Data - UploadSiteHostedPictures API Call*
 http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/ebay/UploadSiteHostedPictures.html#Request.PictureData

**(Request sent to eBay)**

```
HTTP Headers

X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL:867
X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME:dev-name
X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME:app-name
X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME:cert-name
X-EBAY-API-SITEID:siteid
X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME:UploadSiteHostedPictures
```

-

```
XML Request

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UploadSiteHostedPicturesRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <PictureData>Base64BinaryData</PictureData>
  <RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken>token</eBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
  <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
</UploadSiteHostedPicturesRequest>
```

**(Response returned by eBay)**

```
XML Response

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<UploadSiteHostedPicturesResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Timestamp>2014-05-04T20:37:08.751Z</Timestamp>
  <Ack>Failure</Ack>
  <Errors>
    <ShortMessage>Schema XML request error.</ShortMessage>
    <LongMessage>Schema XML request error: Bad character or insufficient number of characters in hex string.</LongMessage>
    <ErrorCode>20170</ErrorCode>
    <SeverityCode>Error</SeverityCode>
    <ErrorParameters ParamID="0">
      <Value>Bad character or insufficient number of characters in hex string</Value>
    </ErrorParameters>
    <ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>
  </Errors>
  <Version>871</Version>
  <Build>E871_CORE_MSA_16805861_R1</Build>
</UploadSiteHostedPicturesResponse>​
```

​